# Connect Antenna to GPS Module ET314AC

Tags: arduino-mega, gps

How can I connect antenna to GPS Module ET314AC?(it is not on a breakout board). I have an antenna like this one [GPS Active Antenna](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/1575-42MHZ-Magnetic-base-GPS-active-Antenna-with-SMA-Plug-connector-for-GPS-receivers-and-Mobile/1531700595.html) and Here is the datasheet of ET314AC[ET314AC Datasheet](https://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjADahUKEwil6qrq4vnIAhVBhRoKHQePBOM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.szstoton.com%2Fres%2Fstotongps%2Fpdres%2F201203%2F20120320163340251.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFOZ31eexhFJWxNYqHvN-QWt4GoEA).I want to connect it manually without any connectors or other things in fact I want to cutoff the connector from antenna.

Comment: Just solder the center wire to the ANT pin, and the outer shielding to the GND pin.

Comment: What about power supply? How can I connect battery to that antenna as it is an active antenna?

Comment: Have you actually read the datasheet? It's plainly there in black and white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the datasheet!

> **V_ANT_IN**
>
> This pin is reserved an external DC power supply for active antenna.
>   If using 2.85V active antenna, pin 19 has to be connected to pin 20.
>   If the bias voltage of active isn’t 2.85V,you can input bias voltage of you need to this pin.

So just wire the antenna to the RF_IN pin and GND, and connect pin 19 to +3.3V (since your antenna is 3.3V not 2.85V).

Comment: i got the point :)